# need to copy data from one table to other table with small chunks

Tags: mysql

I want to copy the data from table T1 to table T2 using.

There are 170 billion records in Table T1.

we tried Using a standard SQL statement like "insert into T2 select * from T1 where date>='01-01-2022' and date'01-02-2022';" is creating severe performance problems or a DB outage.

I don't mind if it takes many hours if I replicate data slowly from T1 to T2 with a limit of 1 record also fine(expecting small chunks).

how to use stored procedures to automate this operation.

Any tool can assist us in copying data into a few rows at a time for inserting.

Comment: How many rows matches the condition `.. where date >= '01-01-2022' and date < '01-02-2022'`? i.e. what is average rows per day amount? Calculate the time chunk which contains ~5000-10000 rows and iterate with this chunk over your table.

Comment: that is a sample condition, we need to copy for last 5 years of data.
not per day , goal is we need T1 table entire data in T2.

Comment: I see. Nevertheless - what is average rows per day amount?

Comment: 'date>='01-01-2022' and date'01-02-2022';"' - is date a string then? and the second date test is missing an operator (<=??) And is this a one off or ongoing process?

Comment: This discusses a chunking mechanism based on the PK:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored procedure may look like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE copy_by_chunks (
    IN date_start DATETIME,
    IN date_end DATETIME,
    IN chunk_in_hours INT
    )
BEGIN
    REPEAT
        INSERT INTO table2
            SELECT * 
            FROM table1 
            WHERE created_at >= date_start
              AND created_at < LEAST(date_start + INTERVAL chunk_in_hours HOURS, date_end);
        SET date_start = date_start + INTERVAL chunk_in_hours HOURS;
        -- if you want to make a pause between chunks then use (for 1-second pause)
        -- SET date_start = date_start + INTERVAL chunk_in_hours + SLEEP(1) HOURS;
    UNTIL date_start >= date_end END REPEAT;
END
```

Recommended chunk size is one which provides a copying of 5k-10k rows.

Of course you must check the provided parameters values correctness (neither parameter is NULL, date_start is less than date_end and so on) and break the procedure if they're incorrect. Also you may add copying progress printing.

Comment: how to add copying progress printing in above stored proc?

Comment: Add something like `INSERT INTO sometable (somecolumn) SELECT created_at` into the cycle. And query this data periodically. For example..

Comment: Chunking by the `PRIMARY KEY` is more efficient.  Also, beware of duplicate `created_at` values.

Comment: for first our  data is copied fine  but for next hours data is not copying still loop is continuing. i need to change something in below condition?
SET date_start = date_start + INTERVAL chunk_in_hours HOURS;

Comment: @Akina for first hour data copying went fine with this proc but for next hours data is not copying still loop is continuing. i need to change something in below condition? SET date_start = date_start + INTERVAL chunk_in_hours HOURS;